# Can't get an Entity from db

Tags: hibernate, criteria, spring-4

I have a postgree db. And spring+hibernate. When i wan't to get entity by any criteria, it is return me 0 length list. Looks like some dependency are missed, or like entity isn't recognized like Entity.

My maven config:
    ...

```
   <spring.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
   <hibernate.version>3.6.9.Final</hibernate.version>
....   
<!-- Spring framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Spring and Transactions-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring ORM support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
```

my spring config

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.helper.api,com.helper.db.model"/>

<bean id="eyeDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${db.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${db.user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernate3AnnotatedSessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="eyeDataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedPackages">
        <list>
            <value>com.helper.db.model</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/xxxxxxxxx_db</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">xxxxxxxxx</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">qwerty123</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

So problem is

```
session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM account").list()
```

This is returns correct data. i have 1 record in table. that was returned
But it was simple SQL. When i change it to equal criteria

```
session.createCriteria(AccountEntity.class).list()
```

it has no return me anything. 
AccountEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account", schema = "public", catalog = "XXXXXXXX_db")
public class AccountEntity {
    private int mId;
    private String mName;
    private String mPassword;
    private Collection<AccountInProductEntity> mAccountInProductsById;
    private Collection<ProductEntity> mProductsById;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    public int getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        mId = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 250)
    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        mName = name;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 50)
    public String getPassword() {
        return mPassword;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        mPassword = password;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
       ....
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        ....
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "accountByAccountId")
    public Collection<AccountInProductEntity> getAccountInProductsById() {
        return mAccountInProductsById;
    }

    public void setAccountInProductsById(Collection<AccountInProductEntity> accountInProductsById) {
        mAccountInProductsById = accountInProductsById;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "accountByOwnerId")
    public Collection<ProductEntity> getProductsById() {
        return mProductsById;
    }

    public void setProductsById(Collection<ProductEntity> productsById) {
        mProductsById = productsById;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was in spring config
i used

```
   <property name="annotatedPackages">
       <list>
          <value>com.tac.helper.db.model</value>
        </list>
   </property>
```

instead

```
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.tac.helper.db.model</value>
        </list>
    </property>
```

Comment: You can mark your answer as correct, so the question can be shown as answered in the search.

Comment: yes will do it in 2 days, with stackowerflow politic